# How can I get a frequency count of values delimited by comma in a pandas dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I'm trying to create a count vector of a some stackoverflow metadata (not actually what I'm doing but similar). So the DataFrame could look something like this:

```
question:    description:      tags:
Q1           desc1             java, android
Q2           desc2             python, machine learning
Q3           desc3             javascript, Node.js
```

If I would like to create a frequency count with of each individual tag instead of a combination of tags, how would I do that?

I know that I could use `df.groupby('tags').count()`, but that would only consider `java, android` to be its own category, rather than considering `java` to be a category and `android to be a separate category.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by regex `,s\+` for comma with one or more whitespaces, then create `Series` by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and last get counts by [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
out = df['tags'].str.split(',\s+', expand=True).stack().value_counts()
print (out)
python              1
javascript          1
machine learning    1
java                1
android             1
Node.js             1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks! I had some instincts that I could use `split` in some way but wasn't sure exactly how.